# How many bytes are required to hold N decimal digits

Tags: c, algorithm, delphi

I have a string of arbitrary length representing a decimal integer value and converting this string into a big integer number in plain binary format (not BCD, more than 64 bits).

I am looking for a good simple estimate how many bytes will hold N decimal digits for sure without using floating-point arithmetics.

Comment: 1) Does your big int library have some `Length` function? 2) Why do you want to avoid floating point?

Comment: It will depend how it is stored. For standard encoding, each digit uses 4 bits, so nBytes=(nDigits+1)/2. You should also consider using compression, even in-memory compression, with some fast algorithm. Ratio will vary, but you'll save space for sure. See also if your data may have some patterns, like storing a delta between values (after sort e.g.), which will even more increase compression.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without using floating point arithmetic: For `N` decimal digits, you need

```
(98981 * N) / 238370 + 1
```

bytes. 98981/238370 is a good rational approximation (from above) to `log(10)/log(256)` (the 9<sup>th</sup> convergent), integer division truncates, therefore add 1. The formula is tight for `N < 238370`, the number of bytes needed to represent `10^N - 1` is exactly given by that, it overestimates for `N` a multiple of 238370 and **really large** `N`. If you're not too afraid of allocating the odd byte too much, you can also use `(267 * N) / 643 + 1`, `(49 * N) / 118 + 1`, `(5 * N) / 12 + 1`  or, wasting about 10% of space, `(N + 1) / 2`.

As @Henrick Hellström points out, in Delphi one would have to use the `div` operator for integer division (missed the delphi tag).

Comment: For clarity, the / operator will result in a floating point division. Use the div operator.

Answer (score 6):

You need this many bits: `ceil(N/log10(2))`.  Round up to the next multiple of 8, i.e., `ceil((N/log10(2))/8)+1` bytes.

Comment: Without floating-point arithmetic: since log10(2) =~ 3.3, you can just compute `N*3.5/8 = (N*3 + N/2)/8`.  @CodeInChaos: `ceil` is supposed to round up. In any case, the integer-only formula will overestimate.

Comment: I think a simple estimate can be based on the fact that 10 bits holds 3 decimal digits for sure.

Comment: @zvrba: that's not good enough. Suppose that the exact quotient is 10.0001 (and some more digits), but due to floating point rounding errors the value you pass to `ceil` is 9.9999. Then `ceil` will round it to 10 instead of 11. If you're trying to allocate enough space for something, underestimating is catastrophic whereas overestimating by a byte is usually fine, so you have to be cautious of inaccuracies if you use floating-point arithmetic to do it.

Comment: That said, I think in this case you're OK, because the `+1` you add when converting from bits to bytes is enough to guarantee that your byte result is never an underestimate even if your bit result is. The bad case is an "exact result" of `(8*N) + 0.0001`, requiring `N+1` bytes, but that comes out as floating point `(8*N) - 0.0001`. You `ceil` to `8*N`, divide to `N`, allocate `N+1` bytes, everyone's happy.

Answer (score 1):

`((size_t)ceil(N/log10(2)) + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT`

Now, `1/log10(2)` ~= `3.32` can be approximated as `10.0/3`=`3.3(3)`.

So, without floating point it would be at most `(((size_t)N*10+2)/3 + CHAR_BIT - 1) / CHAR_BIT` C bytes.

Watch for overflows when `N` is big.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [fixed point arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic)

> The maximum value of a fixed-point type is simply the largest value
>   that can be represented in the underlying integer type, multiplied by
>   the scaling factor; and similarly for the minimum value.
>   For example, consider a fixed-point type represented as a binary
>   integer with b bits in two's complement format, with a scaling factor
>   of 1/2f (that is, the last f bits are fraction bits): the minimum
>   representable value is −2b-1/2f and the maximum value is (2b-1-1)/2f.